# How to fix Vertex Adding in Curve Editing?

Tags: edit-mode, bezier-curves

Per [Blender docs](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/curves/editing/other.html#add-vertex), when in edit mode, one can add extra vertices to a Bezier curve by ctrl-RMB.

When I try to do this, the new point is not placed at the cursor position, but at the origin of the curve.

[image: screenshot]

I'm sure it worked for me in the same file not that long ago; I must have changed some settings, but can't figure which ones. How do I get the default behavior back?

Answer (score 2):

I figured out it's due to transforming scale (`S Y 0`) to the whole object in the object mode instead of applying it to the nodes in the edit mode.